# How to build a python bot for Teams? How to deploy the same in my PROD server?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would want to build a bot in python. I would want to to do various rest calls using that bot. Can this be done in Teams and deployed in PROD LINUX server?

I have python bot in slack and that works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 15):

Bots built for Microsoft Teams are made using the Microsoft Bot Framework, which has a Python SDK you can use, or you can use straight REST calls if you prefer. See:

- Teams app docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview
- Bot Framework docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

For chat bots, it doesn't matter what OS you use to host your service.

Comment: Seems like the bot can be deployed only using .NET or Javascript. How would I develop using python? Should I need to download echobot and customize it?

Comment: You can find a full set of Python samples here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples (use the ones marked for Teams).

Comment: For Detailed info ->

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/python/bot-builder-python-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft recently updated a lot of their tools, plus their documentation is horrible.  I spent an enormous amount of time sifting through it, and here is my distilled version:

1. you create your bot handler using this code as a starting point: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot
2. you register its URL in MS Bot framerwork here: https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new
3. you add MS Teams as a channel