# Microsoft Teams bot using Python

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a project that involves sending adaptive cards to Group Chats (not channels) and I also want to receive any response from users and follow up to execute other actions (Update card, Log down responses, Comments etc...). From what I've gathered, "Incoming Webhooks" does not work in sending actionable messages to Group Chats and a  quick search led me to believe that creating a Teams bot is the best solution for this.

My question is this:
 Am I able to create a Teams bot using Python? Are there any disadvantages v.s. using another language?

Thing I've tried:
Microsoft Flow (limitations in retrieving responses and updating cards with response)

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269902/how-to-build-a-python-bot-for-teams-how-to-deploy-the-same-in-my-prod-server/70931212#70931212

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's absolutely possible to do this! Of course you'll need to skill up on things like [Creating a bot for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams), which in turn builds on the Microsoft Bot Framework underneath, so there's some learning there, but Python is a very popular language for this. Just as one example, see [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#receive-a-message), and notice that "python" is one of the languages for which examples are shown.

A good place to start, aside from the Teams article I linked above, is probably this link: [Create a bot with the Bot Framework SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/python/bot-builder-python-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)